# multithreading - slower than single threading

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

When I run my program with multiple threads instead of single thread it gets slower, isn't it supposed to be faster? The program is supposed to go through all directories starting from a start directory and find and print all files named X. Heres the code:

```
while(!done) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if(!list_isEmpty(dirList)) {
            DIR *dir;
            struct dirent *d;
            char *folder;

            folder = strdup(list_inspect(1, dirList));
            list_remove(list_inspect(1,dirList), dirList);
            if(folder == NULL) {
                perror("failed strdup on path\n");
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
                continue;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            dir = opendir(folder);
            if(dir == NULL) {
                perror(folder);
                free(folder);
                continue;
            }
            while ((d = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
                if(strcmp(d->d_name, ".")==0 || strcmp(d->d_name, "..")==0) {
                    continue;
                }
                searchBasedOnType(folder, info, d);
            }
            closedir(dir);
            free(folder);
        }
        else {
            if(sleepCounter == info->nrthr-1) {
                done = true;
                pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
                break;
            }
            else {
                sleepCounter++;
                pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
                sleepCounter--;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);                
            }
        }   
    }
```

Here is also an example of the function searchBasedOnTypes call functions with mutex etc:

```
char currentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
        struct stat buf;

        strcpy(currentPath,f);
        if(currentPath[strlen(currentPath)-1] != '/') {
            strcat(currentPath, "/");
        }
        strcat(currentPath, d->d_name);
        if(lstat(currentPath, &buf) == -1){
          perror(currentPath);
          return;
        }

        if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            char *newDir = malloc(sizeof(currentPath));
            if(newDir == NULL) {
                perror("Failed allocating memory for path\n");
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
                return;
            }
            strcpy(newDir, currentPath);
            printf("insert %s\n", newDir);
            list_insert(newDir, dirList);
            printf("done\n");
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }
        if(strcmp(name,d->d_name) == 0) {
            printf("%s\n",currentPath);
        }
```

Can somebody help me find what might slow the program down when this is ran with multiple threads and maybe a solution? Thank you for all help and advice in advance!

Comment: Does each thread work on a separate physical drive?

Comment: no, they are all on the same drive, why?

Comment: Well, a lot of asynchronous disk I/O requests from multiple threads can overwhelm the disk driver system that is trying to minimize head movements.  This can result in physical head thrashing that is detrimental to overall perfomance.  Certainly, multiple threads can be useful when searching multiple drives, (especially when they differ widely in performance, or can 'fail' eg. when there are networked drives), attempting what you suggest on one disk needs testing to see if any improvement at all is possible, (and it's quite possible that even two threads will advrsely affect performance).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I understand!

Comment: Adding threads is not a panacaea. Of course introducing I/O contention is not likely to confer benefits...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People often things threads are the computational equivalence of bacon (makes everything better).

**In reality:** Multiple threads don't always speed things up. Multiple threads usually only speed things up if your threads are accessing different hardware resources that can be serviced in parallel. Two threads running CPU-bound tasks on two different cores that don't share memory (or rarely share memory) will probably be faster. If they're sharing memory or hitting the same disk, there's a good chance they're going to contend.

Since the disk is by far the slowest resource that you're program is dealing with, I'm not at all surprised that you aren't seeing any speedup. Try the same experiment with multiple disks (one thread per disk), and you'll probably see an improvement.

Also, the more synchronization your program has (mutex locks) the less parallelism you will usually have. So, performance will suffer further.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you have several threads and your code is "perfect" (not writing the same memory at once, cache-friendly and no mutex) but still you have the problem that several threads are slower than a single thread, you should look for library functions that are not thread safe. An example of this is the random() function from stdlib.h. If you are using it in your threads, your program will be slower in multiple threads than in a single thread. The solution in this case is to look for thread safe equivalents, like rand_r()